# How to convert GIF to a mp4 video in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-packages, flutter-video-player, flutter-ffmpeg

How to convert GIF to a mp4 video in Flutter? With flutter_ffmpeg or any other packages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Method 1:**

Using [flutter_ffmpeg](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_ffmpeg/install) is really easy and you can do a lot of other things with the package.

To set up the package add this in `pubspec.yaml`

```
dependencies:
  flutter_ffmpeg: ^0.4.2
```

add this in your `build.gradle` located here android/build.gradle

```
ext {
    flutterFFmpegPackage  = "min"
}
```

finally in your code

```
import 'package:flutter_ffmpeg/flutter_ffmpeg.dart';
  ...
  ...
  final FlutterFFmpeg _flutterFFmpeg = FlutterFFmpeg();
  final String inputFile = ".../input.gif"; //path of the gif file.
  final String outputFile = ".../output.mp4"; //path to export the mp4 file.

  await _flutterFFmpeg
        .execute("-f gif -i $inputFile $outputFile")
        .then((rc) => print("FFmpeg process 1 exited with rc $rc"));
```

*Note: If you are exporting anywhere other than your app's directory, the file would have to be scanned or you wouldn't be able to use the file.*

**Method 2:**

If all you wanna do is convert a `.gif` to `.mp4` then you can save a lot of space by just renaming `.gif` to `.mp4` and it'll work. You can also rename the **same file** from `.mp4` to `.gif`. But, this method wouldn't work if you wanna convert an original `.mp4` file to `.gif`.

Here's an example on how to rename a file:

```dart
  Directory appDocDir = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
  String appDocPath = appDocDir.path;
  //Let's assume that "$appDocPath/awesome.gif" is the path of the file.
  await File("$appDocPath/awesome.gif").rename("$appDocPath/awesome.mp4");
```

*NOTE : You have to enter the full path of the file in `rename()`.*

You can again rename the same file back to `.gif`, and it would work. But, this method wouldn't work if you want to convert an `.mp4` file that was never converted from a `.gif`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but can you apply more details and code of how to **Rename** a file?

Comment: I got this error while renaming it: `OS Error: No such file or directory, errno = 2`

Comment: are you sure you entered the correct path of the file?

Comment: Hi @ShaanMephobic, the mp4 file which converted from about way, it can not play, its totally black. Do you know why? Thanks.

Comment: @ChuongLeVan Maybe this would have something to do with `Media Scanner` intent. Could you try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/69025529/14595863 ?

Comment: I found out a way, just add this command "-f gif -i $inputFile -movflags faststart -pix_fmt yuv420p -vf 'scale=trunc(iw/2)*2:trunc(ih/2)*2' $outputFile" it should be work.

Comment: ```final gifExist = File(globals.gifFile!.path).existsSync();
     if (gifExist) {
     debugPrint(globals.gifFile!.path);
     final file = await File(globals.gifFile!.path).rename('${globals.gifFile!.path}.mp4');
     debugPrint(file.path);
     ImageGallerySaver.saveFile(file.path, isReturnPathOfIOS: true);
    }``` @ShaanMephobic always give me cannot be saved to the photo library: Error Domain=AVFoundationErrorDomain Code=-11829 (may be damaged)

Comment: note my gif is in getApplicationDocumentsDirectory
```Directory documentDirectory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
            File file = File(path.join(documentDirectory.path, path.basename('tempGif')));
            await file.writeAsBytes(globals.tempGif!);```
any idea?? @ShaanMephobic?

Comment: Maaaan hours on that... Couldn't make the mp4 from GIF to use for ImageGallerySaver. It was always failing - tried to rename, tried to duplicate with different name (.mp4) - no way to make it work. But anyway having mp4 which doesn't loop would not even be satisfactory. And I wasn't trusting the legend saying we cannot save gif to camera roll as whatsapp does - no problem. Then this morning after 15' in I had the brilliant idea to give up on ImageGallerySaver but rather use **share_plus** - Job done with no pain...

Answer (score 0):

Short answer:  use Share_Plus. Long answer: in comment in the only other answer